# Is there a way to make a custom css button transparent against the background?

Tags: css

I am trying to make a custom play button using css. I get to the point where I have this:

```css
.play{
 height: 74px;
 border-width: 37px 0px 37px 67px;
 padding-right: 0;
 border-color: transparent transparent transparent #33ffff;
        margin-top:25px;
        margin-left:25px;
 margin-bottom:25px;
}

#body{
       background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <button class="play" id="playB"></button>
</div>
```

I am just wondering if there is any way to make the `border-color: transparent transparent transparent #33ffff;` actually transparent when there is a background behind it? I don't want to see the grey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, the gray is the background. set it to transparent as well.

```css
.play{
 height: 74px;
 border-width: 37px 0px 37px 67px;
 padding-right: 0;
 border-color: transparent transparent transparent #33ffff;
        margin-top:25px;
        margin-left:25px;
 margin-bottom:25px;
 background: transparent
}

#body{
       background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <button class="play" id="playB"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    .play{
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 50px 0 50px 200px;
        border-color: transparent transparent transparent #007bff;

    }
```

Comment: Please update your answer if you have additional information. Do not put it into a comment

Comment: Is this your own solution for the question, or is this additional information that should be added to the question itself?